# I can't update Joomla metadata

Tags: joomla, metadata

My Joomla website had been hacked by someone and he modify the website title and description which show in the google search (when i search my site in google I found my site with hacker title and description ) .

I found no changes in  the metadata and description in the Joomla site configuration.

Is there other place that override my Joomla setting?

Comment: Which Joomla version? Is this description and title only in Google Search or do you see them also within the browser on the homepage or on any other website? Did you update and reset to a backup now?

Answer (score 0):

It could be anywhere, but quickly check the template main file(s) usually `/templates/your_template/index.php`.

Don't spend more than two minutes on this. Your site was hacked: you need to clean it first. Restore a good backup, update it, find out how they got in.
If you don't have a backup, reinstall Joomla! over it and all extensions and template, that may buy you some time.